# How to change the size of large operators uniformly?

Tags: math-operators, large-symbols

In my opinion, the large operators are a little large, especially off lines. **So is there any way to descale them uniformly?** A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\sum_i x_i+y_i.\]

\end{document}
```

One possible way is to change the font sizes that large symbols use, but I don't know the details.

Comment: If you're willing to use the `newtxmath` package, you can load it with option `smallerops`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the list in `amsmath.sty`:

```
\ifx\@tempa\@tempc
  \global\let\coprod@\coprod
  \gdef\coprod{\DOTSB\coprod@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigvee@\bigvee
  \gdef\bigvee{\DOTSB\bigvee@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigwedge@\bigwedge
  \gdef\bigwedge{\DOTSB\bigwedge@\slimits@}
  \global\let\biguplus@\biguplus
  \gdef\biguplus{\DOTSB\biguplus@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigcap@\bigcap
  \gdef\bigcap{\DOTSB\bigcap@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigcup@\bigcup
  \gdef\bigcup{\DOTSB\bigcup@\slimits@}
  \global\let\prod@\prod
  \gdef\prod{\DOTSB\prod@\slimits@}
  \global\let\sum@\sum
  \gdef\sum{\DOTSB\sum@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigotimes@\bigotimes
  \gdef\bigotimes{\DOTSB\bigotimes@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigoplus@\bigoplus
  \gdef\bigoplus{\DOTSB\bigoplus@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigodot@\bigodot
  \gdef\bigodot{\DOTSB\bigodot@\slimits@}
  \global\let\bigsqcup@\bigsqcup
  \gdef\bigsqcup{\DOTSB\bigsqcup@\slimits@}
\fi
```

You can use it in order to accomplish you wish (which I wouldn't).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\gdef\coprod{\DOTSB\reduce@op\coprod@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigvee{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigvee@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigwedge{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigwedge@\slimits@}
\gdef\biguplus{\DOTSB\reduce@op\biguplus@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigcap{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigcap@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigcup{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigcup@\slimits@}
\gdef\prod{\DOTSB\reduce@op\prod@\slimits@}
\gdef\sum{\DOTSB\reduce@op\sum@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigotimes{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigotimes@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigoplus{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigoplus@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigodot{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigodot@\slimits@}
\gdef\bigsqcup{\DOTSB\reduce@op\bigsqcup@\slimits@}

\def\reduce@op#1{\mathop{\mathpalette\reduce@@op{#1}}}
\def\reduce@@op#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.8}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}%
  \else
    #2%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\sum\bigcup\bigvee$

\[
\csname sum@\endcsname_{k=1}^n % for comparison
\sum_{k=1}^n \bigcup \bigvee
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a new display version, you could just define a scaled version of `\sum` as a new operator:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\ssum}{\scalebox{1.1}{$\sum$}}
```

[image]

If you want to change all the large operators in the document without manual editing of each occurrence, you can use the `\scaleobj` command from the `scalerel` package:

```
\let\oldsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sum}{\scaleobj{.8}{\oldsum}}
```

Then all `\sum`s will be scaled to 80% of their standard height, whether displayed or inline:

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\let\oldsum\sum
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sum}{\scaleobj{.8}{\oldsum}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\displaystyle{\oldsum_i x_i+y_i\text{ vs. }\sum_i x_i+y_i}$ & \texttt{displaystyle}\\[3ex]
$\oldsum_i x_i+y_i\text{ vs. }\sum_i x_i+y_i$ & \texttt{textstyle}\\
$\scriptstyle \oldsum_i x_i+y_i\text{ vs. }\sum_i x_i+y_i$ & \texttt{scriptstyle}\\
$\scriptscriptstyle \oldsum_i x_i+y_i\text{ vs. }\sum_i x_i+y_i$ & \texttt{scriptscriptstyle}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need a more general way which can change all the large operators.

Comment: @M.Logic Probably cannot (it's just a character in a font, and I don't think it's feasible to change font size of particular character type without changing that of the whole formula... unless you apply hacks like redefining some lower-case command?). Do manually, or loop over them and change one by one.

Comment: @M.Logic The simple answer, for a systematic approach, is to find and use a font that already presents operators in your desired size.

Comment: @M.Logic: I posted an update. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Specifically, what I need is a way to uniformly change all the large operators such as `\sum`, `\bigcup`, `\bigvee` and so on, but not a local way to change only one or two operators.

Comment: @M.Logic: There aren't that many different large operators. You can just add `\let\oldbigcup\bigcup\let\bigcup\relax\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigcup}{\scaleobj{.8}{\oldbigcup}}` to your preamble and it will change `\bigcup` globally. Do it for each large operator in your document.